# Deriving $P(X∈A,(X,Y)∈B)$ from independence of random vectors

Tags: random-variables, independence

Let's say the $n$-dimensional $X$ with distribution $μ_X$ and $m$-dimensional $Y$ with distribution $μ_Y$ are independent on $(Ω, F , P)$. Then we know that:
$$P((X,Y)∈B)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} \:P((x,Y)∈B)μ_X(dx)$$ for any $B∈\mathscr{B}^{m+n}$.
How can we derive
$$P(X∈A,(X,Y)∈B)=\int_{\mathbb A} \:P((x,Y)∈B)μ_X(dx)$$ for any $A∈\mathscr{B}^n$ and $B∈\mathscr{B}^{m+n}$ from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a new $B$ with same probability :
\begin{align*}
B'=\{ (x,y) : x\in A, (x,y)\in B \}
\end{align*}
You then get that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X\in A, (X,Y)\in B) &= \mathbb P((X,Y)\in B')\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n} P((x,Y)\in B')\mu_X(dx)\\
&=\int_{A} P((x,Y)\in B')\mu_X(dx)\\
&=\int_{A} P((x,Y)\in B)\mu_X(dx)\\
\end{align*}
By noting that when $(x,y)\in B'$, you have $x\in A$ and when $x\in A$, then $(x,y)\in B'\Leftrightarrow (x,y)\in B$.

It remains to prove the measurability of $B'$, you get it from the fact that
\begin{align*}
B' = B\cap  A\times \mathcal Y\in\mathcal B^{m+n}
\end{align*}
Where $\mathcal Y$ is the support of $Y$.

Comment: Thanks, though I am a bit confused on how to build $B'$. Say, $A=[0,r]$ and $B=\{(x,y):x +y ≤r^{2}\}$, how can I define $B'$?

Comment: In that case $B'=\{(x,y) : x\in[0,r], x+y\leq r^2\}$.

Comment: My bad $B$ is $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le r^2\}$. Yeah, I get that part, but when I want to do the integral, how can I write $((,)∈′)$?

Comment: The last integral I write is the one You want right ? There is no $B'$ in it. We use $B'$ to rewrite everything.